# CListCtrl get item index

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

How do I get an item's index number using the caption text? I'm using CListCtrl class of MFC. I have the item's caption text, can I get the index for that item and then update its text. It will be helpful if you could provide an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CListCtrl::FindItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xetd6cd%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)  (MSDN link with example)